# Concatenating an i-adj with a no-adj/noun

Tags: adjectives

I have a question regarding concatenating i-adj with a no-adj/noun.

This is the sentence I'm attempting to translate: Those are black lenses to protect your eyes against sunlight. My try: 暗くて目を日光から守るのためのレンズです

However if I read I would be a bit confused because i would think that 暗くて might define 目 even if it's not ending in い

Answer (score 3):

それらは、あなたの目を日光から守るための**黒い**レンズです。